# Can I still develop apps for iOS6 in 2017?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios6

I'm using XCode 8.2.1 and see that the earliest SDK it allows me to use is iOS8. I have a couple ideas for apps that use dedicated older devices (iPod 4/iPhone 4), and would like to use iOS6.

- Is developing for iOS6 still possible in 2017?
- Would apple accept apps developed for iOS6 to the App Store?
- Can I download iOS 6 SDK within XCode8 or do
  I need to download earlier version of XCode?

Comment: You can certainly develop for iOS 6 with an old enough version of Xcode and an old enough Mac system to run it on. But, although Apple might accept a new app linked against iOS 10 but somehow backward compatible to iOS 6, they won't accept a new app linked against iOS 6.

Comment: To add to what @matt I guess your older devices wont run 64bit , so more exact answer is, even you target higher iOS (if they support it) no, and you wont be able to soon enough you will be developing for no use.  http://www.macworld.com/article/3163248/ios/the-future-of-ios-is-64-bit-only-apple-to-stop-support-of-32-bit-apps.html Apple won't support older devices forever on their AppStore, even if the device is actually usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, but iOS 6 is deprecated 
you can develop iOS 6 application in Xcode 5 or 6, but you can't publish your application